# Do pure qudit states lie on a hypersphere in the Bloch representation?

Tags: quantum-state, bloch-sphere, state-space-geometry

It is known that every state $\rho$ of a $d$-level system (or if you prefer, qudits living in a $d$-dimensional Hilbert space) can be mapped into elements of $\mathbb R^{d^2-1}$ through the mapping provided by the *Bloch representation*, by writing it as
$$\rho=\frac{1}{d}\left(I+\sum_{k=1}^{d^2-1} c_k \sigma_k\right),$$
with $\{\sigma_k\}$ traceless Hermitian matrices satisfying $\operatorname{Tr}(\sigma_j\sigma_k)=d\delta_{jk}$ and $c_k\in\mathbb R$.
We can then consider the mapping $f:\rho\mapsto f(\rho)\equiv\boldsymbol c\in\mathbb R^{d^2-1}$.
One can also show that the set of all states maps into a compact set in $\mathbb R^{d^2-1}$, and furthermore characterise the boundary of this set in "spherical coordinates", as shown for example in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/425101/58382).

Moreover, as shown for example [in the answers to this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/5603/55), the purity of a state $\rho$ translates into the norm of $f(\rho)$ (i.e. its distance from the origin): $\operatorname{Tr}(\rho^2)=(1+\|f(\rho)\|^2)/d$.
It follows that if $\rho$ is pure, that is $\operatorname{Tr}(\rho^2)=1$, then $\|f(\rho)\|=\sqrt{d-1}$. *This means that the set of pure states is a subset of the hypersphere $S^{d^2-2}\subseteq\mathbb R^{d^2-1}$ with radius $\sqrt{d-1}$.*

However, the pure states *do not* cover this hypersphere: the boundary of the set of states is *not* comprised of pure states (see e.g. [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/6009/55)), and many (most) elements on $S^{d^2-2}$ do not correspond to physical states. This tells us that the set of pure states does *not* lie on a hypersphere in the Bloch representation (which must obviously be true, as we know that the set of pures has a much smaller dimension).

But then again, this does not (I think?) rule out the possibility that the set of pure states lies on *some* lower-dimensional hypersphere $S^{2d-3}$ embedded in $\mathbb R^{d^2-1}$. Is this the case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Upon some reflection, the answer is that no, they most definitely do not.

The easiest way to see this is to observe that there are $d^2-1$ orthogonal directions in the Bloch representation (*i.e.* orthogonal Hermitian traceless operators) containing pure states. This means that that the pure states are not contained in any linear subspace of dimension less than $d^2-1$, and thus in particular cannot be contained in any lower-dimensional hypersphere.

More specifically, given any orthogonal basis of Hermitian traceless operators $\{\boldsymbol\sigma_j\}_{j=1}^{d^2-1}$, and any versor $\hat{\mathbf n}\in\mathbb R^{d^2-1}$ with $\|\hat{\mathbf n}\|=1$, there are always pure states in the direction $\boldsymbol\sigma_{\hat{\mathbf n}}\equiv\hat{\mathbf n}\cdot\boldsymbol\sigma$ (this follows from the fact that the operator norm satisfies $\|\boldsymbol\sigma_{\hat{\mathbf n}}\|>0$ and the characterisation in spherical coordinates explained e.g. [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/425101/58382)).
It follows that there cannot be less than $d^2-1$ elements of $\mathbb R^{d^2-1}$ whose span contains the set of pure states.

---

## A concrete example: three-level systems

Consider a generic pure state of a three-level system:
$$|\psi\rangle=\cos\alpha|0\rangle+e^{i\phi}\sin\alpha \cos\beta |1\rangle+e^{i\theta}\sin\alpha\sin\beta|2\rangle,$$
for all $\alpha,\beta,\phi,\theta\in\mathbb R$.
Let us also use the standard operatorial basis for this space (the matrices used at the bottom of [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/425101/58382)):

$$
Z^{(1)}=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0&0 \\ 0 & -1&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix},
\quad
Z^{(2)}=\sqrt{\frac{3}{6}}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0&0 \\ 0 & 1&0\\0&0&-2\end{pmatrix},
$$
\begin{align}
X^{(12)}=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1&0 \\ 1 & 0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix},
\quad
X^{(13)}=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0&1 \\ 0 & 0&0\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix},
\quad
X^{(23)}=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0&0 \\ 0 & 0&1\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
Y^{(12)}=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\begin{pmatrix}0 & -i&0 \\ i & 0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix},
\quad
Y^{(13)}=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0&-i \\ 0 & 0&0\\i&0&0\end{pmatrix},
\quad
Y^{(23)}=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0&0 \\ 0 & 0&-i\\0&i&0\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
Then, the surface covered by the pure states in $\mathbb R^8$ has the following parametrisation:
\begin{cases}
\langle Z^{(1)}\rangle&=\sqrt{3/2} (\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha\cos^2\beta),\\
\langle Z^{(2)}\rangle&=\sqrt{3/6} [\cos^2\alpha+\sin^2\alpha(\cos^2\beta-2\sin^2\beta)],\\\hline
\langle X^{(12)}\rangle&=\sqrt{3/2}\sin(2\alpha)\cos\beta \cos\phi,\\
\langle X^{(13)}\rangle&=\sqrt{3/2}\sin(2\alpha)\sin\beta \cos\theta,\\
\langle X^{(23)}\rangle&=\sqrt{3/2}\sin^2(\alpha)\sin(2\beta) \cos(\phi-\theta),\\\hline
\langle Y^{(12)}\rangle&=\sqrt{3/2}\sin(2\alpha)\cos\beta \sin\phi,\\
\langle Y^{(13)}\rangle&=\sqrt{3/2}\sin(2\alpha)\sin\beta \sin\theta,\\
\langle Y^{(23)}\rangle&=\sqrt{3/2}\sin^2(\alpha)\sin(2\beta) \sin(\phi-\theta).\tag A
\end{cases}

To easily check that these points do indeed lie on a hypersphere (which we also know from [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/6047/55) must have a radius of $\sqrt2$), just run the following snippet in Mathematica:

```
$Assumptions = Element[{\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Theta], \[Phi]}, Reals];

expvalZ1[\[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_, \[Phi]_:0, \[Theta]_:0] = Sqrt[3/2]*(Cos[\[Alpha]]^2 - Sin[\[Alpha]]^2*Cos[\[Beta]]^2); 
expvalZ2[\[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_, \[Phi]_:0, \[Theta]_:0] = Sqrt[3/6]*(Cos[\[Alpha]]^2 + Sin[\[Alpha]]^2*(Cos[\[Beta]]^2 - 2*Sin[\[Beta]]^2)); 
expvalX12[\[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_, \[Phi]_, \[Theta]_:0] = Sqrt[3/2]*Sin[2*\[Alpha]]*Cos[\[Beta]]*Cos[\[Phi]]; 
expvalX13[\[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_, \[Phi]_:0, \[Theta]_] = Sqrt[3/2]*Sin[2*\[Alpha]]*Sin[\[Beta]]*Cos[\[Theta]]; 
expvalX23[\[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_, \[Phi]_, \[Theta]_] = Sqrt[3/2]*Sin[\[Alpha]]^2*Sin[2*\[Beta]]*Cos[\[Phi] - \[Theta]]; 
expvalY12[\[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_, \[Phi]_, \[Theta]_:0] = Sqrt[3/2]*Sin[2*\[Alpha]]*Cos[\[Beta]]*Sin[\[Phi]]; 
expvalY13[\[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_, \[Phi]_:0, \[Theta]_] = Sqrt[3/2]*Sin[2*\[Alpha]]*Sin[\[Beta]]*Sin[\[Theta]]; 
expvalY23[\[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_, \[Phi]_, \[Theta]_] = Sqrt[3/2]*Sin[\[Alpha]]^2*Sin[2*\[Beta]]*Sin[\[Phi] - \[Theta]];

Simplify[Total[(#1[\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Phi], \[Theta]]^2 & ) /@ {expvalZ1, expvalZ2, expvalX12, expvalX13, expvalX23, expvalY12, expvalY13, expvalY23}]]
```

Now, what sort of $4$-dimensional surface in $\mathbb R^8$ is this?
I don't know a full answer to this, but if it was a hypersphere, then the sections would look like lower-dimensional hyperspheres (e.g. plotting only in two dimensions should result in a series of circles). This is most definitely not the case.

Indeed, for completeness, here is what some of the sections look like (I will again use Mathematica for the plotting):

#### $Z^{(1)}, Z^{(2)}$ section

These coordinates only depend on the $\alpha,\beta$ parameters. It follows that the full space is contained in a sort of "tubular region" with the following triangular 2D section:

```
ParametricPlot[{expvalZ1[\[Alpha], \[Beta]], 
  expvalZ2[\[Alpha], \[Beta]]}, {\[Alpha], 0, Pi}, {\[Beta], 0, Pi}]
```

[image]

So again, most definitely ***not*** what a hypersphere would look like.

#### Two-dimensional $X^{(ij)}$ sections

The two-dimensional sections obtained using two of the three available $X^{(ij)}$ coordinates look like ellipses when varying $\alpha,\beta$ for fixed $\theta,\phi$ (with the principal axes varying with $\theta,\phi$). Interestingly, if we instead vary $\theta,\phi$ for fixed $\alpha,\beta$, the sections look instead like rectangles.
I won't include the plots, but you can use the following code to show these sections:

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{expvalX12[\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Theta], \[Phi]], 
   expvalX13[\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Theta], \[Phi]]}, {\[Alpha], 0, 
   Pi}, {\[Beta], 0, Pi}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}],
 {{\[Theta], 0}, 0, Pi, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{\[Phi], 0}, 
  0, Pi, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]

Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{expvalX12[\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Theta], \[Phi]], 
   expvalX13[\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Theta], \[Phi]]}, {\[Theta], 0, 
   Pi}, {\[Phi], 0, Pi}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}],
 {{\[Alpha], 0}, 0, Pi, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{\[Beta], 0},
   0, Pi, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

#### Three-dimensional $X^{(ij)}$ section

This is where it starts to look pretty cool.

If we vary $\alpha,\beta$ for $\theta,\phi$ fixed, we get this nice 3D shape (sorry for the poor quality, SE doesn't allow more than 2MB for images):

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot3D[{expvalX12[\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Theta], \[Phi]], 
   expvalX13[\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Theta], \[Phi]], 
   expvalX23[\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Theta], \[Phi]]}, {\[Alpha], 0, 
   Pi}, {\[Beta], 0, Pi}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  PlotRange -> Evaluate[{{-#, #}, {-#, #}, {-#, #}} &@Sqrt@2]],
 {{\[Theta], 0}, 0, Pi, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{\[Phi], 0}, 
  0, Pi, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, ControlPlacement -> Right]
```

[image]

Changing the values of $\phi,\theta$ mostly just changes the scales of the surface, without modifying its structure.
Here is a better quality, still picture of this surface:

[image]

The $Y^{(ij)}$ sections have pretty much the same structure, modulo changing the values of $\phi,\theta$.

So yea, in conclusion, definitely not a hypersphere.

---

PS:
For anyone that wants to see how the pure states move in the overall $8$-dimensional surface, you can use the following code to see the point corresponding to the given state in the $X,Y$ and $Z$ sections at the same time, changing the values of the $\alpha,\beta,\theta,\phi$ parameters (the blue dot represents the state for the given values of the parameters):

```
pointOnXSection[\[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := \
{expvalX12[\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Theta], \[Phi]], 
   expvalX13[\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Theta], \[Phi]], 
   expvalX23[\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Theta], \[Phi]]};
pointOnYSection[\[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := \
{expvalY12[\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Theta], \[Phi]], 
   expvalY13[\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Theta], \[Phi]], 
   expvalY23[\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Theta], \[Phi]]};
pointOnZSection[\[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := \
{expvalZ1[\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Theta], \[Phi]], 
   expvalZ2[\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Theta], \[Phi]]};
Manipulate[
 GraphicsRow[{
   Show[
    ParametricPlot3D[
     pointOnXSection[\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Theta], \[Phi]], {\[Alpha], 
      0, Pi}, {\[Beta], 0, Pi}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
     PlotRange -> Evaluate[{{-#, #}, {-#, #}, {-#, #}} &@Sqrt@2], 
     AxesLabel -> {1, 2, 3}, ImageSize -> 400, 
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity@0.7], RotationAction -> "Clip"],
    Graphics3D[{Blue, PointSize@0.03, 
      Point@pointOnXSection[dot\[Alpha], 
        dot\[Beta], \[Theta], \[Phi]]}]
    ],
   Show[
    ParametricPlot3D[
     pointOnYSection[\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Theta], \[Phi]], {\[Alpha], 
      0, Pi}, {\[Beta], 0, Pi}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
     PlotRange -> Evaluate[{{-#, #}, {-#, #}, {-#, #}} &@Sqrt@2], 
     AxesLabel -> {1, 2, 3}, ImageSize -> 400, 
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity@0.7], RotationAction -> "Clip"],
    Graphics3D[{Blue, PointSize@0.03, 
      Point@pointOnYSection[dot\[Alpha], 
        dot\[Beta], \[Theta], \[Phi]]}]
    ],
   Show[
    ParametricPlot[
     pointOnZSection[\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Theta], \[Phi]], {\[Alpha], 
      0, Pi}, {\[Beta], 0, Pi}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
     PlotRange -> Evaluate[{{-#, #}, {-#, #}} &@Sqrt@2], 
     AxesLabel -> {1, 2, 3}, ImageSize -> 300, 
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity@0.7]],
    Graphics[{Blue, PointSize@0.03, 
      Point@pointOnZSection[dot\[Alpha], 
        dot\[Beta], \[Theta], \[Phi]]}]
    ]
   }, ImageSize -> 800],
 {{\[Theta], 0}, 0, Pi, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{\[Phi], 0}, 
  0, Pi, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{dot\[Alpha], 0, "\[Alpha]"}, 0, Pi, 0.01, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{dot\[Beta], 0, "\[Beta]"}, 0, Pi, 0.01, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 ControlPlacement -> Right]
```

Comment: The "nice shape" is known as Roman surface or Steiner surface. More info on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_surface), [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RomanSurface.html).

Comment: @TheVee very interesting, thanks for the pointer. Do you know if there is an easy way to see why this particular surface arises in this context?

Comment: Not sure. It's mentioned in [this paper](http://www.math.brown.edu/~banchoff/howison/newbanchoff/publications/pdfs/9Vertex.pdf) on page 19 with respect to RP^2. The set of pure qutrit states is CP^2, but there's a lot of parallels between the two (as the paper also discusses).

Comment: Well, it's quite simple after all. When you fix $\theta$ and $\phi$ the ratios between the three amplitudes are fully determined by ratios of three *real* numbers, which form RP^2.